# Authenticate to JIRA using node-jira module

Tags: node.js, jira

I need to connect my application to JIRA API, and I found module [node-jira](https://github.com/steves/node-jira), that should help me with that.

However, I'm having problem with authentication.

Here's what I done (nothing special, but for some reason, it doesn't work):

```
var JiraApi = require('jira').JiraApi;

var jira = new JiraApi('https', '[url to my jira project]', 443, '[username]', '[password]', '2.0.alpha1');

jira.getCurrentUser(function(error, issue) {
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
  console.log('success');
});
```

I receive:

```
401: Error while getting current user
```

Any ideas what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into source code, looks like mentioned method isn't making request properly.

It does `this.request` instead of `this.doRequest`. I'll submit it to github repo.

Comment: I just ran into this after asking what I think is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279599/authentication-error-401-when-using-node-jira-module . Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This may give you some ideas;   it's not a call to get an issue from JIRA, but it shows how to set up an Atlassian API call (from Google Sheets).  You just need to plug in the right URL and Endpoint (for a JIRA issue as an example).

```
function showAtlassian() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('atlassianform')
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Atlassian Login');
}

function processAtlassian(myForm) {
  var username = myForm.un;
  var userpw = myForm.pw;
  var myencoded = Utilities.base64Encode(username+":"+userpw);
  var headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic " + myencoded};
  var options = {
      'method': 'get',
      "contentType" : "application/json",
      "headers": headers,
      'muteHttpExceptions': false
    }
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
url = 'https://---your domain --/wiki/rest/api/user/current';
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var data = JSON.parse(response)
    var result = ui.alert( 'got valid connection userkey ' + data.userKey );
  } catch(error) {
    var result = ui.alert( 'invalid user or password: url: '+ url +' err: ' + error.toString());
    getatlassian();
  }
}

function getatlassian() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  showAtlassian()
}
```