# Authentication Error 401 when using node-jira module

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to read an issue using a https://github.com/steves/node-jira , however I am getting an an error

```
 401: Unable to connect to JIRA during findIssueStatus.
```

Here is the code that I am using the code bellow on localhost:8433

```
var jiraApi = require('jira').JiraApi;

var config = {
    "username": "name@email.com",
    "password": "password",
    "port": 443,
    "host": "company.atlassian.net"
}

var issueNumber = "ABC-1";

var jira = new jiraApi('https', config.host, config.port, config.username, config.password, '2');
jira.findIssue(issueNumber, function(error, issue) {
    console.log('Status: ' + issue.fields.status.name);
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? My problem was related to bug in code, I submitted fix, and it was merged into master. So if you got the code recently, fix should be in there. I'm not near computer atm, so I can't take a closer look at the code that your calling (from node library).

Comment: just had the same problem, just downloaded the latest jira node module today, so it should have the fix no? Still getting 401.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the source to the jira api library and found the error message.
Apparently "unable to connect to jira" actually means "unable to find issue".

```
    # Unable to find issue
    @jira.request.mostRecentCall.args[1] null, statusCode:401, null
    expect(@cb).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        '401: Unable to connect to JIRA during findIssueStatus.')


https://github.com/steves/node-jira/blob/master/spec/jira.spec.coffee
```

okay, never mind that.
I was able to hit the jira api with curl and found I was getting a 403 access denied.
It would seem that your login has to have the jira api access turned on so probably that's what's wrong.
So it is able to connect, but you're getting kicked out because your login has no access.